# De Rham cohomology of $\mathbb{RP^n}$

Tags: algebraic-topology, projective-space, de-rham-cohomology

I have to calculate the De Rham cohomology of $\mathbb{RP^n}$ using the Mayer-Vietoris sequence.

I first started by considering $\mathbb{RP^n}=S^n/\sim $ where $\sim$ is the antipodal identification. Then I wrote $\mathbb{RP^n}$ as the union of the sets

$U=S^n- \{(0,...0,1)\}$

and

$V=S^n- \{(1,0,...,0)\}$

But when I start using Mayer-Vietoris sequence I don't know how to proceed. Do I need to calculate it by induction on the order of the cohomology? Have you any hints or references in which it is solved?

Thank you.

Comment: Well you should try to first figure out the cohomology of $U$, $V$, and $U \cap V$. Then you should try to figure out what the induced maps on cohomology are. Then you can hope that can exactness will help to figure out the cohomology groups.

Comment: @DKS These are precisely the steps I can't do. Is there a place where it's explained?